# IQueryable optional OrderBy with PredicateBuilder and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm using PredicateBuilder and LINQKit from [Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to construct a LINQ query that has optional parameters, optional OrderBy, optional Skip() and optional Take().

PredicateBuilder makes it easy to build the optional parameters, but I'm having problems with the other stuff. To simplify the issue:

This works

```
var query = this.MyContext.Things.AsExpandable.Where(predicate).OrderBy(s => s.Name);
return query.ToList();
```

I want to do something like this, so I can wrap the OrderBy in an if. It doesn't work however, the results are not in name order.

```
var query = this.MyContext.Things.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
query.OrderBy(s => s.Name);
return query.ToList();
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm an NHibernate convert and still getting to grips with LINQ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a re-assignment to your `query` variable - `OrderBy()` (same as all other standard query operators) returns a new `IQueryable<T>`:

```
query = query.OrderBy(s => s.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks! Easy to miss the simple things when your brain is stuck on a different way of doing things (like NHibernate).